# Join three tables in one sql query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a query with two tables and I need to JOIN one more to it so I can get the product model corresponding to the order.

What I have so far is

```
$sql = "SELECT 
  o.order_id, 
  o.name, 
  o.value, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.order_id,  o.name, o.value SEPARATOR ',') AS Options 
FROM `order_option` AS o 
LEFT JOIN `order` AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id
where oo.order_status_id = 2 
group by o.order_id";

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
$options=$row['Options'];
print "$options";

    PRINT "<br>-------------------<br>";
}
```

Now, I have a third table that contains the product model for each order. The table is called "order_product", it has two fields "order_id" and "model" (one record per order).

What I have now as a result now is

ID, option1: Valude, option2: Value

What I want to accomplish is

ID, MODEL, option1: Valude, option2: Value

Where the model should come from the third table "order_product"

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you know why you used the `LEFT JOIN` to join the two existing tables, right? because joining three tables isnt much of a diffrence... but I feel that you could also go for a crossjoin here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should serve the purpose:

```
SELECT 
o.order_id, 
order_product.model,
o.name, 
o.value, 
GROUP_CONCAT(o.order_id,  o.name, o.value SEPARATOR ',') AS Options 
FROM `order_option` AS o 
LEFT JOIN `order` AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id
LEFT JOIN order_product ON o.order_id = order_product.order_id
where oo.order_status_id = 2 
group by o.order_id
```

Comment: it does worked, but I had to add order_product.model to the GROUP_CONCAT as well

Comment: the only problem I am left with is that now for each option (every option is on a separate row for each order ID) I have the ID and the MODEL printed twice. Any idea how to get read of the second print, but still have printed the options. This is what I mean. Now I have

ID, Model, option1:Value, ID, Model, option2:Value

And what I need is: ID, MODEL, OPTION1:Value, OPTION2:Value

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT table1.* from table1
JOIN table2 as lnk1 on table1.id = table2.tab1_id AND
JOIN table3 as lnk2 on table2.id = table3.tab2_id -->here you can use table1 as to join also
```

but keep in mind that the heirarchy of joining bec some of tables may related with previous tables but may not joined yet

Comment: Ofcourse I didnt used your code as it is...i Just gave you a glance...that's it...but both ans are same for joining...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT 
  o.order_id, 
  o.name, 
  o.value, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.order_id,  o.name, o.value SEPARATOR ',') AS Options,
  op.model 
FROM `order_option` AS o 
INNER JOIN `order` AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id
INNER JOIN `order_product` AS op on oo.order_id = op.order_id
where oo.order_status_id = 2 
group by o.order_id";
```

Like that ?

Just do an additional join on your order ID number since it links across all tables.